# Add a row with random numbers every n amount of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame.

```
A | B | C | D
0   4   8   9
1   5   8   9
2   6   8   9
3   7   8   9
```

I would like to add a row every second row with a random number, so it will look like that.

```
A | B | C | D
0   4   8   9
1   5   8   9
596 596 596 596
2   6   8   9
3   7   8   9
123 123 123 123
```

The following code from another question thanks to PiR square, add zero to every 2nd row. How can I modify it to add a random number every second row OR an increment of the previous random number, such as.

```
A | B | C | D
a   a   a   a
b   b   b   b
0   0   0   0
c   c   c   c
d   d   d   d
1   1   1   1
```

Here you can see, that it starts with 0 then increments to 1 on the next second row

This code adds zero to every second row from the other StackOverflow question

```
s = pd.Series(0, df.columns)
f = lambda d: d.append(s, ignore_index=True)

grp = np.arange(len(df)) // 2
df= df.groupby(grp, group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your lambda function as, Change the range as per your requirement in `randint`:

```
f = lambda d: d.append(pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=1).repeat(4), df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

or:

```
f = lambda d: d.append(pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=1).tolist()[0], df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```